# Understanding per cpu structure in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cpu, internals

I am studying linux kernel and sometimes I don't understand what kernel developers want in a particular piece of code. So I was reading through timers in kernel and a timer is created using a struct timer_list variable, that contains a per cpu pointer. I tried to understand a little better this per cpu variable so I was looking in linux kerenl, how things are getting created.
So I have taken different structures from kernel and listed the #defines to integrate things and see a clear picture, what actually is happening.

structures from all this started

```
struct timer_list {
    /*
     * All fields that change during normal runtime grouped to the
     * same cacheline
     */
    struct list_head entry;
    unsigned long expires;
    struct tvec_base *base;//pointer to per cpu variable, so I checked what is inside

    void (*function)(unsigned long);
    unsigned long data;

    int slack;

#ifdef CONFIG_TIMER_STATS
    int start_pid;
    void *start_site;
    char start_comm[16];
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
    struct lockdep_map lockdep_map;
#endif
};
```

the base pointer is a struct like this

```
struct tvec_base {
    spinlock_t lock;
    struct timer_list *running_timer;
    unsigned long timer_jiffies;
    unsigned long next_timer;
    unsigned long active_timers;
    struct tvec_root tv1;
    struct tvec tv2;
    struct tvec tv3;
    struct tvec tv4;
    struct tvec tv5;
} ____cacheline_aligned;//??why such a name __cacheline_aligned

struct tvec_base boot_tvec_bases;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(boot_tvec_bases);
static DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct tvec_base *, tvec_bases) = &boot_tvec_bases;//from here I am a little puzzeled as the way things are written been assigned.
```

DEFINE PER CPU is such a simple #define to understand, wish it was

```
    #define DEFINE_PER_CPU(type, name)                  \
        DEFINE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, "")

#define DEFINE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, sec)             \//?? what exactly we achieve here
    __PCPU_DUMMY_ATTRS char __pcpu_scope_##name;            \
    extern __PCPU_DUMMY_ATTRS char __pcpu_unique_##name;        \
    __PCPU_DUMMY_ATTRS char __pcpu_unique_##name;           \
    __PCPU_ATTRS(sec) PER_CPU_DEF_ATTRIBUTES __weak         \
    __typeof__(type) name

#define __PCPU_DUMMY_ATTRS                      \
    __attribute__((section(".discard"), unused))//i think it is a section in map file, but already kernel is built and I am builing a timer module, so what does it do?
```

If anyone have good experience in linux internal can you just point me in the right direction.

Some specific questions which if answered can make me understand whole thing,

`static DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct tvec_base *, tvec_bases) = &boot_tvec_bases;

1)what does this mean? this address '&boot_tvec_bases' is going where?

2) why a name `____cacheline_aligned;`
 choosen. Does it do anything special?

3)what is

```
#define DEFINE_PER_CPU_SECTION(type, name, sec)
```

sec here?

Comment: This is not a question, please restate as a question.  Feel free to ask as several sub questions, but the important thing about a question is that you can put a question mark at the end.  Right now it's too general.

Comment: ok I will break it down

Comment: `____cacheline_aligned` as comes from the name is a special treatment of alignment to the structure. Depending on CPU type it might be 32 bytes, 64 bytes, or else.

Comment: `sec` is section where to look for CPU attributes AFAIU.

Comment: Initially all the pointers to the structures in the specific section has same value, i.e. address of  `boot_tvec_base`.

Answer (score 0):

1. timer.h:36: extern struct tvec_base boot_tvec_bases;
2. See [____cacheline_aligned_in_smp for structure in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947962/cacheline-aligned-in-smp-for-structure-in-linux)

> ____cacheline_aligned instructs the compiler to instantiate a struct or variable at an address corresponding to the beginning of an L1
>   cache line, for the specific architecture, i.e., so that it is L1
>   cache-line aligned. ____cacheline_aligned_in_smp is similar, but is
>   actually L1 cache-line aligned only when the kernel is compiled in SMP
>   configuration (i.e., with option CONFIG_SMP). These are defined in
>   file include/linux/cache.h

3.http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-5

> Per-CPU variables are an interesting 2.6 kernel feature. When you
>   create a per-CPU variable, each processor on the system gets its own
>   copy of that variable. This may seem like a strange thing to want to
>   do, but it has its advantages. Access to per-CPU variables requires
>   (almost) no locking, because each processor works with its own copy.