# Struct definition in C

Tags: c, struct

I am looking in to C code of my project and it mentioned as below. What does the statement `nsq1[1]` mean here at the end of the struct definition.

```
struct iec_apdu {
    unsigned char start;
    unsigned char length;
    unsigned short NS;
    unsigned short NR;
    struct iec_unit_id asduh;
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned short ioa16;
            unsigned char ioa8;
            iec_type1 obj[1];
        } sq1;

        struct {
            unsigned short ioa16;
            unsigned char ioa8;
            iec_type1 obj;
        } nsq1[1];
}
```

Comment: Read about [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You probably should use them. And this forum is not for learning purposes, you should take time to read some good C programming book, and also [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: Your code is missing at least one `};`.  Superficially, it looks like someone is trying to use the 'struct hack' in a union at the end of a structure definition.  It's a bit hard to be sure because of the syntax error.  If it is an attempt at a struct hack, then you should get it upgraded to use flexible array members.  I'm glad it's you who has to suffer from that code; I would be in a state of loathing of whoever it was who tried to impose that on me.

Comment: `nsq1` is an array (of length 1) of anonymous `struct`-s (with fields `ioa16`, `ioa8`, `obj`). It is also a member of some anonymous `union`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11

Answer (score 3):

It is an array of 1 element of type struct nsq1. Something like:
int x[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
nsq1[1];
```

It is array of object you can access struct element using nsq1[0] and nsq1[1] since you have create two object for the struct