# recursive datatypes in haskell

Tags: c, pointers, haskell, type-safety, algebraic-data-types

Consider the following definition taken from a tutorial at http://www.haskell.org :

```
data Tree a                = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) 
fringe                     :: Tree a -> [a]
fringe (Leaf x)            =  [x]
fringe (Branch left right) =  fringe left ++ fringe right
```

I am unclear about what happens at runtime when the function fringe is executing.

When compiling the expression `fringe left` , 
(1) does the compiler somehow already know if the `left` tree is a `Branch` or
a `Leaf` - i.e. it only operates on statically known trees - or (2) does it emit some `if`/`switch` like conditions to check if the `left` tree is a `Leaf` or a `Branch`

If it is the later i.e. (2), then, why is this supposed to be more typesafe than the equivalent C function which basically would look just like above except that there is only one type floating around (pointer to a node).

Comment: The answer is (2). If that were not the case `fringe` would have to be generating separate versions of itself for every "shape" of binary trees. Type-safety is a different concept that compile-time evaluation.

Comment: "[...] the equivalent C function [in which] there is only one type floating around" -- but there is only one type here: `Leaf "foo"` and `Branch (Leaf "foo") (Leaf "bar")` both have the same type, `Tree String`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
fringe (Leaf x)            =  [x]
fringe (Branch left right) =  fringe left ++ fringe right
```

is exactly equivalent to a function of a single variable that then immediately does a pattern match:

```
fringe t = case t of
    Leaf x            -> [x]
    Branch left right -> fringe left ++ fringe right
```

So this answers your first question as (2): "it emit[s] some `case`-like conditions to check if the left tree is a `Leaf` or a `Branch`".

As for why it's safer than what you would do in C, well, what would you do in C?

Usually you end up storing a **product** of a tag which shows if something is `Leaf` or `Branch`, and a payload which is the untagged union of `a` and `(Tree a, Tree a)`. Then, the code you write is along the lines of the following (which is probably not 100% legal C but should get the point across):

```
enum TreeTag { Tree_Leaf; Tree_Branch; };

struct Tree {
  TreeTag tag;
  union payload {
    struct { 
      int x;    // yeah let's not touch on parametric polymorphism here...
    } Leaf;
    struct {
      Tree l;
      Tree r;
    } Branch;
  };
};


switch (t.tag) {
  case Tree_Leaf: ... use t.payload.Leaf.x here
  case Tree_Branch: ... use t.payload.Branch.left and t.payload.Branch.right here
}
```

The problem is that there is nothing statically preventing you from accidentally using `t.payload.Branch.left` in the `Tree_Leaf` case and so on. Also, there's nothing statically preventing you to do something like

```
t.tag = Tree_Branch;
t.payload.Leaf.x = 42;
```

which would lead to an invalid value of "type" `Tree`.

Comment: Moreover, in c, you dont benefit for any exhaustivity/redundancy check which assure that you're not forgotting any case

Comment: Using C11, it is possible to write a tagged union using a relatively [simple syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932782/3234959), exploiting anonymous unions/structs. There is still no strong type safety, of course.