# C - what advantage do anonymous structures offer?

Tags: c

I would like to know why and when one would explicitly choose to use an anonymous structure like so:

```
typedef struct my_struct_t my_struct_t;

struct my_struct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{   

    my_struct_t obj1 =
    {
        .a = 33,
        .b = 44
    };

    return 0; 
}
```

rather than doing:

```
typedef struct my_struct_t my_struct_t;

struct my_struct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{   

    my_struct_t obj2;
    obj2.a = 55;
    obj2.b = 66;

    return 0; 
}
```

What advantages does the former offer over the latter and/or vice-verca?
thanks

Comment: There is no anonymous structure in either of your codes.

Comment: That's an initializer list, not an anonymous structure.

Comment: it just means you don't have to repeat `obj2.` for every member. This becomes more valuable if you have nested structures and arrays.

Comment: @Barmar could you plese show en example of what an anonymous structure is? I was 100% sure this is what is called an anonymous struct...

Comment: Your code actually shows the difference between *initialization* and *assignment*, it is analogous to asking "why would I do `int x = 5;` instead of `int x; x = 5;`

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11

Comment: Is the post about initialization vs. assignment or what is an anonymous `struct`?

Comment: Anonymous structures are very convenient when you have them nested into other structs/unions. This way you don't have to type the full "path" to the fields.

Comment: I wonder how you ever obtained *the wrong idea*, and note that you seem to ask questions as I would consider prematurely... Could it be that the method you use to learn isn't working for you, and what you should actually be asking for is an "example" of a better method to learn?

Answer (score 3):

An anonymous struct is useful when you want to nest structures/unions without assigning a particular "meaning" to the inner structures. It lets you access the members of an inner structure as if they were a direct member of the enclosing struct. See the following example taken from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct):

> Similar to union, an unnamed member of a struct whose type is a struct
>   without name is known as anonymous struct. Every member of an
>   anonymous struct is considered to be a member of the enclosing struct
>   or union. This applies recursively if the enclosing struct or union is
>   also anonymous.
>
> ```
> struct v {
>    union { // anonymous union
>       struct { int i, j; }; // anonymous structure
>       struct { long k, l; } w;
>    };
>    int m;
> } v1;
>
> v1.i = 2;   // valid
> v1.k = 3;   // invalid: inner structure is not anonymous
> v1.w.k = 5; // valid
> ```

The code you showed actually has nothing to do with anonymous structs. It is rather an example of using an initializer list with designated members.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's *one* use. When working with unions, it's implementation defined what you'll get when reading a union member that wasn't last written to. But, in the case of structures, you can inspect the common initial sequence of fields. Here's an example to illustrate:

```
#include <assert.h>

struct S1 {
  int  type;
  char value;
};

struct S2 {
  int   type;
  float value;
};

union U {
  struct S1 s1;
  struct S2 s2;
};

int main() {
  union U un;
  un.s1.type = 1;
  un.s1.value = 'c';
  assert(un.s2.type == 1);
}
```

As you can see above, it is guaranteed by the C standard that whatever I write to `un.s1.type` I can then read from `un.s2.type`. So far so good. But there's a problem if I try to do something like this instead:

```
union U {
  struct S1 s1;
  int type;
};
```

Now there is no guarantee. We can't read `un.s1.type` from `un.type` under the protection of the standard. But hope is not lost, we can just make it a field of a structure again, an anonymous structure, like so:

```
union U {
  struct S1 s1;
  struct {
    int type;
  };
};
```

The fields of an anonymous structure are "injected" into the enclosing structure or union, so we may refer to `type` by accessing `un.type`. And now were are back to the warm embrace of the standard. Since now we again have two structures with a common initial sequence of fields.

Answer (score 2):

Your example has nothing to do with anonymous structs, but only with initialization vs. assignement. It matters mainly when objects are declared const:

```
const  my_struct_t obj1 =
{
    .a = 33,
    .b = 44
};
```

is correct while this is not:

```
const my_struct_t obj2;
obj2.a = 55;   // error: try to assign to const object
```

Anonymous structures and unions allow members of a sub struct/union to be used as if they were members of the containing sub/union.

Draft n1570 for C11 says at 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers §13 says:

> An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with no tag is called an
>   anonymous structure; an unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier with
>   no tag is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union
>   are considered to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies
>   recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous.

and even gives a (non normative) example:

```
struct v {
    union { // anonymous union
        struct { int i, j; }; // anonymous structure
        struct { long k, l; } w;
    };
    int m;
} v1;
v1.i = 2; // valid
v1.k = 3; // invalid: inner structure is not anonymous
v1.w.k = 5; // valid
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an anonymous struct, that is simply using designated initializers, and you use them particularly when you don't need to provide values for all the members of a complicated struct.

Comment: could you plese show en example of what an anonymous structure looks like? I was 100% sure this is what is called an anonymous struct...