# The use of structs in the queue.h library

Tags: c, macros, queue

I am currently looking into the use of macros in the C language.
To get used to them and to learn I am looking at the queue.h library that allows to create dynamic data structures in C.

You can find the source here:
bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/queue.h

Right now I stumbled upon the following definition:

```
#define SLIST_ENTRY(type) \
    struct { \
    struct type *slh_next;
    }
```

If I am not mistaken this creates a struct with a pointer that will point to the next element in the singly-linked list. 
I just can't figure out, why you have to create the struct. Wouldn't just the pointer be enough?

```
#define SLIST_ENTRY(type) \
    struct type *slh_next
```

I guess if you want to create a doubly-linked list, you would create a struct with next & before pointers. So is this just to be consistent, or does the struct in the SLIST define serve a specific purpose?

PS: how do I format code and links on mobile?

Comment: Why would you write such obfuscated code if you can write in an easy way?

Comment: A header file is **not** a library, it *might* describe the interface of one. In your case, the BSDs typically have the *kernel* source in the `sys` tree, so it's **very likely** not a library interface you're looking at.

Comment: As for the actual usecase, this is done for handling the links in a generic way, but right now, I don't see the need for the wrapping anonymous struct either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it doesn't make much sense when you use it in a single linked list but if you see the definitions of the (double linked) list in the [source code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/sys/queue.h) then its purpose is more clear because now it has two pointers and you just have to add a single `LIST_ENTRY` structure to your data structure.

```
#define LIST_ENTRY(type)                                             \
struct {                                                             \
    struct type *le_next;   /* next element */                       \
    struct type **le_prev;  /* address of previous next element */   \
}
```

`LIST_ENTRY(type)` expands to an anonymous `struct`. Anonymous `struct`s were introduced along with anonymous `union`s in the C11 standard. When an anonymous `struct` or an anonymous `union` is enclosed within another `struct` or `union`, the enclosing structure acquires the fields of the enclosed anonymous structure.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11) and the [example code](https://man.openbsd.org/queue.3#LIST_EXAMPLE):

```
struct entry { 
    ... 
    LIST_ENTRY(entry) entries; 
    ... 
} *n1, *n2, *np;
```

In this case, the fields of `LIST_ENTRY(entry)` become fields of `entry`. So yeah, it's a generalized type of link just as someone said above. Now a function can get the previous and the next element from this structure like this:

```
#define LIST_INSERT_AFTER(listelm, elm, field) do {                 \
    if (((elm)->field.le_next = (listelm)->field.le_next) != NULL)  \
        (listelm)->field.le_next->field.le_prev =                   \
            &(elm)->field.le_next;                                  \
    (listelm)->field.le_next = (elm);                               \
    (elm)->field.le_prev = &(listelm)->field.le_next;               \
} while (0)
```