# What does it mean when define a struct var without identifier in a structure in c language?

Tags: c, structure

In C language, what is the meaning of `struct Animal;` in line # 6?
Is it legal in C89 or C99 or C11?

```
struct Animal {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

struct Cat {
    struct Animal;   // line 6
    int category;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it says "there is a type `struct Animal`", and that's all.  It doesn't do anything useful because line 1 already said that.  When I compile it, I get `x.c:9:18: error: declaration does not declare anything [-Werror]` — `struct Animal;` which is what I'd expect.  It would be a warning if I didn't compile with `-Werror`.

Comment: I've tried the code in VS2015 with a .c file, and it compiled ok, and output: sizeof(struct Animal): 8
sizeof(struct Cat): 12
which looks like there is an "struct Animal" entity in struct cat. So I'm not sure is it legal in C89 or C99?

Comment: It's dubious, but legal.  I have GCC set to very fussy, and any warnings it produces are treated as errors.

Comment: In clang, it looks like meaning nothing, I've tried the code in xcode9, and it outputs: sizeof(struct Animal): 16
sizeof(struct Cat): 4

Comment: Working on a Mac, 64-bit compilation, and suppressing the `-Werror` option, I get size of Animal as 16 and size of Cat as 4, which is exactly what I'd expect.  Your result on VS2015 is curious — I find it hard to explain how you got that result.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't mean much of anything -- and in fact it's a constraint violation.

The language grammar allows

```
struct Animal;
```

in place of a member declaration inside a struct or union declaration.  But it violates a language rule ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.2.1 paragraph 2):

> A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous structure or
>   anonymous union shall contain a struct-declarator-list.

This is a "constraint", which means that violating it requires a diagnostic. (A non-fatal warning message qualifies as a diagnostic.)

If you had written:

```
struct Cat {
    struct Animal foo;
    int category;
};
```

then the `foo` would be a "declarator". The constraint I quoted above means you're not allowed to omit it.  gcc and clang both warn about this by default ("declaration does not declare anything") and reject it with `-Wpedantic-errors`.

(Anonymous structs and unions were added to the language in C11, and are [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8932707/827263), but the code in your question is not an anonymous struct.)

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` makes GCC reject the code, so I'm not sure if it's actually allowed.