# Access struct field within another struct without referring to inner struct

Tags: c, struct

Suppose I have a struct that is defined as the following:

```
struct entity {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And a struct that uses it as a member:

```
struct player {
    struct entity position;
    char* name;
};
```

If I write the following code then I get an error:

```
struct player p;
p.x = 0;         //error: 'struct player' has no member named 'x'
```

What I have been doing so far is writing a function that takes a player struct and returns the value by doing `return player.position.x`.

Is there a compiler flag, or other method, that allows me to "flatten" (I'm not sure if that's the correct phrase) the struct and allows me to access the x variable like I have shown above? I realize that this might be ambiguous if there is also an integer named x inside player as well as in entity.

Please note I will be using the *entity* struct in multiple structs and so I cannot use a anonymous struct inside *player*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are anonymous structs and unions useful for in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11)

Comment: I do not believe that my question is a dupe of the aforementioned question. I edited the question to hopefully address that!

Comment: Succinctly, no — especially if an anonymous structure is not applicable.

Comment: Great thanks. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a macro, we can make a type generator:

```
#define struct_entity(...) \
struct __VA_ARGS__ {       \
  int a;                   \
  int b;                   \
}
```

Then we can instantiate that type as either a tagged or anonymous structure, at will:

```
struct_entity(entity);

struct player {
  struct_entity();
  const char *name;
};

int main() {
    struct player player;
    player.a = 1;
    player.b = 2;
    player.name = "bar";
}
```

This code is closer in intent to what you want, and doesn't have the UB problem of the [approach of declaring just the structure members in the macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808732/1329652). Specifically, there is a structure member inside of `struct player`, instead of individual members. This is important, because padding reduction and reordering of members may be performed by the compiler - especially on embedded targets. E.g. `composite_1` and `composite_2` below do not necessarily have the same layout!:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct sub_1 {
  int a;
  void *b;
  char c;
} sub_1;

typedef struct sub_2 {
  void *d;
  char e;
} sub_2;

typedef struct composite_1 {
  int a;
  void *b;
  char c;
  void *d;
  char e;
} composite_1;

typedef struct composite_2 {
  struct sub_1 one;
  struct sub_2 two;
} composite_2;

// Some of the asserts below may fail on some architectures.
// The compile-time asserts are necessary to ensure that the two layouts are
// compatible.
static_assert(sizeof(composite_1) == sizeof(composite_2), "UB");
static_assert(offsetof(composite_1, a) == offsetof(composite_2, one.a), "UB");
static_assert(offsetof(composite_1, b) == offsetof(composite_2, one.b), "UB");
static_assert(offsetof(composite_1, c) == offsetof(composite_2, one.c), "UB");
static_assert(offsetof(composite_1, d) == offsetof(composite_2, two.d), "UB");
static_assert(offsetof(composite_1, e) == offsetof(composite_2, two.e), "UB");
```

Comment: Standard C does not allow the compiler to reorder the elements of a structure.  Obviously, there might be compilers on specific platforms that do such reordering, presumably using some platform-specific directive (compilation option, pragma or similar) to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Put succinctly, the answer is "No".  This is especially true if you've looked at questions such as [What are anonymous structs and unions useful for in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11) and found them not to be the solution.

You can look at C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p13) for more information about structure and union types in general (and ¶13 specifically for more information about anonymous members, and ¶19 for an example).  I agree that they are not what you're after; they involve a newly defined type with no tag and no 'declarator list'.

Answer (score 0):

You can define then as MACROs:

```
#define ENTITY_MEMBERS int x; int y
struct entity{
    ENTITY_MEMBERS;
}

struct player {
    ENTITY_MEMBERS;
    char* name;
};
```

Actually this is how you mimic C++ single inheritance in C.