# Overloading a function with void

Tags: c

Trying to overloading a function in C programming language with `_Generic`. Have found examples:

- https://www.quora.com/Does-C-support-function-overloading
- [How to achieve function overloading in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/how-to-achieve-function-overloading-in-c)

This the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void display_float(float dispid) ;
void display_int(int dispid) ;
void display_void(void) ;

#define display(x) _Generic((x), \
          float: display_float, \
          int: display_int,  \
          default: display_float  \
)(x)

void display_void(void){
    printf("display id: 0\n") ;
}

void display_float(float dispid){
   printf("display id: %f\n", dispid) ;
}

void display_int(int dispid){
    printf("display id: %d\n", dispid) ;
}

void main(void){

    display(5) ;
    display(6.5) ;
}
```

Now I also want to overload the function with `display()`. Meaning the function would intake a `void`, call the function `display_void()`, and display 0. Can't seem to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:

Also, see the examples [here](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html). One of the examples (I think) is passing a pointer to a void. Can this be implemented?

Comment: You can't overload on the absence of a parameter. Your choice of `display_float` as the default in the `_Generic` is surprising, but changing it to `display_void` won't help much; you'd have to provide an argument to the `display` macro, and that would be passed to whatever function is in the `default` clause, and if that was `display_void`, it would be expecting no arguments. However, `_Generic` expects an _assignment-expression_ as the first argument, and neither an empty token sequence nor `()` is acceptable as an _assignment-expression_ so you can't use `_Generic` to overload on `()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I suspected this. But also see my EDIT 1 in the question.

Comment: Passing pointer to void is easy — yes, that can be handled.  It's passing nothing that is tricky (undoable, I think, even with C11 allowing empty arguments to macros).

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please do not incorporate answers in your question. It invalidates them, and is quite rude to the people who donate their time to answer. If you have a new question about other updated code, post as new question.

Comment: Without better examples (or some genuine [MCVE] in your question itself), the question is unclear and I voted to close it.

Comment: `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: You could define a `display0` macro that takes no arguments and a `display1` macro that takes one argument. You know when you're writing the call how many arguments you're passing, so choosing which macro to invoke isn't much of a burden.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: A reproducible example is given in the question itself. Not sure what more you are asking for. Everyone else seems to understand perfectly what the question is.

Comment: As I answered **it is not about function overloading** so at least the title of the question is wrong, and at least that should be improved; and `_Generic`  should not even suggests overloading, but genericity

Comment: The original title was edited by someone else. Also, the link that I have provided at the very beginning shows that function overloading in C can be done via `_Generic`.

Comment: My claim is that it is about generic functions, not function overloading. See the food for thought in my answer. But I am not a native English speaker (and in France I was educated, even at high school, to choose words carefully)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. [Overload Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments).

```
void display_float(float dispid) ;
void display_int(int dispid) ;
void display_void(void) ;

#define _display_1(x) _Generic((x), \
          float: display_float, \
          int: display_int,  \
          default: display_float  \
)(x)
#define _display_0()  display_void()
#define _display_N(_0,_1,N,...)  _display_ ## N
#define display(...) _display_N(_0,##__VA_ARGS__,1,0)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    display();
    display(1);
    display(1.1);
}
```

Tested on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yglbla).

Note that `, ##__VA_ARGS__` is a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) not described in the C standard.

Comment: Won't work well with `display(stderr);` or `FILE* f = fopen(__FILE__, "r"); display(f);` or on Linux using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) with `struct stat st; stat("/dev/zero", &st);` followed by `display(st);` or `display(&st)`; please improve your answer for `display(stderr)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't get your point. There is no `display(FILE*)` nor `display(struct stat*)` nor `display(struct stat)` overloads, so they shouldn't work. I don't get your point.  If you add them, [they will work](https://godbolt.org/z/zInnn8). Why should `display(stderr)` work? OP didn't requested it. I won't.

Comment: OP dreams of a *generic* `display` thing, and I am trying to explain (sorry, I am not a native English speaker) that such a thing cannot exist (unless OP defines `display_FILE` *explicitly* and `display_stat`, which he does not want to!)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ? `Now I also want to overload the function with display(). Meaning the function would intake a void, call the function display_void()` - this is very specific. We want to write `display()` and make it call `display_void()`. Nothing more, nothing less.  I don't know OP that good to guess what she/he dreams about and does or doesn't want to. The OPs post has like 6 edits, maybe your browser could have messed it up.

Comment: @ Kamil Cuk: then do what I did: vote to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to overloading a function in C programming language

**[C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) does not have any [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)** and **`_Generic` is for [genericity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming)**, *not* for overloading, check that by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Consider switching to C++ (or even better, [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)) which provides function overloading. Notice that it is illegal to have a `void` (not `void*`, just `void`) argument to a C function, so there is no any ["top"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) super-type in C, which would be a super type of other types (and this because of [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) considerations making C a *low-level* programming language, sometimes even called a "[portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) assembler"). Read more about [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) and [type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) please.

If `_Generic` was for overloading, the members of the C11 standard committee - all programming language experts and good enough English writers -  would have named it like `_Overload`, but they wisely did not.

**Food for thought** (assuming both `stderr` and `stdin` works like you want them to work) **:** 
 **what about some hypothetical `display(stderr)` or `display(*stdin)` or `display("abc")` ?**

<sup>(a wrong suggestion below, followed by a better advice)</sup>

#### bad approach

(**this does not work!**)

Your  `display_void` should take some argument, e.g.

```
void display_void(void*p) { printf("p@%p\n", p);
```

Then you might have:

```
#define display_anything(P) display_void((void*)(&(P)))
```

with

```
#define display(x) _Generic((x), \
      float: display_float, \
      int: display_int,  \
      default: display_anything  \
)(x)
```

### better advice

Since that does not work (and it does not), **design your code in some other way**. For example, consider having some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978380/841108). Look into [GVariant](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html) (from Glib) implementation for inspiration.

Comment: Kindly see my EDIT 2.

Comment: Saw that, approved its unrolling, gave a better advice.