# How to get the order of member in a struct

Tags: c, struct

Assuming I have a structure such as:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} TEST1_T;

TEST1_T test1;
```

I can reference test1.a with ((int**)&test1)[0]

And if i have a structure such as:

```
typedef struct {
    int a[15];
    int b[20];
    int c[30];
} TEST2_T;

TEST2_T test2;
```

How can i reference test2.c with it's order in struct like reference test1.b with ((int**)&test1)[1]?

Comment: Use the `offsetof` macro from `<stddef.h>` to get the offset in bytes from the beginning of the struct to one of the members.

Comment: `offsetof` requires you to have the name of the member. This question is asking about accessing a member by a numerical index.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If a or b arrays increase in size, this sort of reference will just keel over.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `((int**)&test1)[0]` results in *undefined behavior* because the effective type of `test1` is `TEST1_T` and it is being accessed using an lvalue expression of incompatible type `int`. See C11/C17 6.5/6-7.

Comment: @IanAbbott: `((int**)&test1)[0]` does not attempt to access the memory using an expression of type `int`; it attempts to access the memory using an expression of type `int *`. If the cast were to `int *`, the behavior would be defined, because C 2018 6.7.2.1 15 says that a pointer to a structure “suitably converted” yields a pointer to its first member, which is an `int`, so the aliasing rule would be satisfied.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point. I think OP and myself meant `((int*)&test1)[0]`. Your reference makes this access OK, but using `((int*)&test1)[1]` to access the `b` member would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a `union`, in this case. You could even use `C11`'s [new anonymous union](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8932707/2472827).

```
#include <stdio.h>

union test1 {
    struct { int a, b; };
    int x[2];
};

union test2 {
    struct { int a[15], b[20], c[30]; };
    int x[15 + 20 + 30];
};

int main(void) {
    union test1 foo = { { 4, 5 } };
    printf("%d %d / %d %d\n", foo.a, foo.b, foo.x[0], foo.x[1]);
    return 0;
}
```